# what component allows me to open a Virtual tour in a popup?

Tags: extensions, form, popup

I'm trying to create a popup by modifying the source code through the editor.
the code is as follows:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('mypage.htm','pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;">popup</a>
```

but once saved the article, I see that the code has been cut.

actually I'm looking for a component that allows me to open a Virtual tour (a web page or a swf file) in a popup. I tried the "simple popup" component, but I use another component called. "pocha panorama" and I can't use them together.

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/16199/120

Comment: Your question's title is irrelevant with what you finally ask.

Answer (score 0):

From **Global Configuration > Text filters** select `No Filtering` for user group you want to. Perhaps, Admin user group.

Editor will not stripe out the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of Engage Box by Tassos Marinos for anything popup/modal related.  It is easy to setup and has lots of extra features like setting cookies, custom page assignments, calling it through buttons, etc.  There are pre-setup modes for newsletter signups, social media, video, as well.

https://www.tassos.gr/joomla-extensions/engagebox